# trying to avoid the "no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf" warning with if_else condition does not work

Tags: r, warnings, min

I have the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 23, 998, 9991, 9992, 1, 2, 3),
                 group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2))

df

     x group
1    1     1
2   23     1
3  998     1
4 9991     1
5 9992     1
6    1     2
7    2     2
8    3     2
```

I now want to go through each group separately and save the minimum of the range of values of `c(998, 9991, 9992)`.
This works for group 1, because group 1 has some values that are within c(998, 9991, 9992). Group 2 doesn't and it is expected to see a warning for group 2:

`no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf`

However, in my code, I added a safety net (if else condition), where I explicitely tell the code to only calculate the minimum if the above condition of values c(998, 9991, 9992) is met. Even if I hard code to only take the minimum in group 1, I still get the above error and I don't know why.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(test = if_else(group == 1,
                        min(x[x %in% c(998, 9991, 9992)], na.rm = TRUE),
                        NA_real_))
```

The result is correct, that's not the problem:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   group [2]
      x group  test
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1   998
2    23     1   998
3   998     1   998
4  9991     1   998
5  9992     1   998
6     1     2    NA
7     2     2    NA
8     3     2    NA
```

But I would have expected that the following warning wouldn't show up:

```
Warning message:
Problem with `mutate()` column `test`.
i `test = if_else(...)`.
i no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
i The warning occurred in group 2: group = 2.
```

Why am I still getting this warning? And is there any way to safeguard the code so that the warning wouldn't appear (i.e. apply it only to thos groups where the calculation of the minimum would be a valid action)?

Comment: Seems related to this issue (closed, but not fixed): [In a grouped mutate, if_else warns it's returning Inf when it isn't](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/5434). That said, with `if_else` (or `ifelse`) you get one `TRUE` / `FALSE` per row and do one calculation _per row_, whereas it seems like you want to perform the test on the group level, and do _one_ calculation per _group_, something like `v = c(998, 9991, 9992)`;    `mutate(test = if(any(x %in% v)) min(x[x %in% v], na.rm = TRUE) else NA_real_)`

Comment: Thanks for hinting to the bug + suggesting the better coding. You are right, I should rather use sth. like if_any.